# Is there a way to run JS without/malformed script tags

Tags: javascript, html, security, xss

I am doing some ethical research on XSS (I take a class on computer programming and web development). My professor has tasked my group to run `alert('xss')` on his test website. Despite my best efforts I couldn't but I ended up finding the filter he is using. Opening tag `<` followed by any character expect for a space, and any HTML encoded characters like `\u003E`. My first thought would be to type `< img src="javascript:alert('xss')">` but the space makes the tag malformed and not run. I've also noticed the title of the website changes based on what is input. If I type `abc()` the title is changed to `abc() - website`. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: @lluisrojass as I stated in the question I can't use HTML encoded characters or opening tags :/ thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: can you share the source code to the site? it might help get abit more context.